# Position bootstrap dropdown when button set to display:none

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

## Description

In VueJS I'm trying to open Bootstrap dropdown menu programmatically by clicking on a word.
I want the menu to appear right under the mouse.

## The problem

The problem is - when I set `display: none;` on the button that displays the dropdown, the menu appears on the top left corner. I've found [solutions](https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/pEFhaLWTht) for HTML, but I struggle to rewrite them to VueJS.

## Minimal working example

My current snippet looks like this: (click the word "click" or remove `display: none;`)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  methods: {
    toggleTest: function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log(this.$refs.clickWord);
      this.$refs.clickWord.click();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-app">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        A column.
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        You should <span v-on:click="toggleTest" onMouseOver="this.style.background='#AFF'" onMouseOut="this.style.background='#FFF'">click</span> a word.

        <div class="dropdown" id="word0">
          <button id="ete" style="display:none" ref="clickWord" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" style="top:100 !important; left:100; position: absolute;">
            <span class="dropdown-item-text">Dropdown item text</span>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with setting the dropdown's button to `display: none` is that it's as if the button is no longer part of the DOM, and the dropdown uses the button's position to position itself.

This problem can be avoided if you instead set the button to `opacity: 0`. It's still invisible, but the dropdown knows it's still there.

The dropdown button with a few tweaked styles:

```html
<button id="ete"
        style="opacity:0; height:0; position:absolute; top:-16px"
        ref="clickWord"
        class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false"></button>
```

Working snippet:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-app">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        A column.
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        You should
        <span v-on:click="toggleTest"
          onMouseOver="this.style.background='#AFF'"
          onMouseOut="this.style.background='#FFF'">click</span>
        a word.

        <div class="dropdown" id="word0">
          <button id="ete"
          style="opacity:0; height:0; position:absolute; top:-16px"
          ref="clickWord" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
          type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false"></button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu"
            style="top:100 !important; left:100; position: absolute;">
            <span class="dropdown-item-text">Dropdown item text</span>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>


<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  methods: {
    toggleTest: function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      // console.log(this.$refs.clickWord);
      this.$refs.clickWord.click();
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Trading `display:none;` for `opacity: 0; max-height: 0;padding:0;` seems to do the trick.

Also note you're loading two different versions of Vue, which might cause unexpected behavior.

---

However, it's still not a good enough solution. The proper solution is to treat the `<span>` element as the dropdown button, removing the button-like styling.

Why? Because the dropdown is positioning itself relative to the current parent, which is the text paragraph. So it will always be aligned to the left side. As for vertical position, it will be correct as long as the trigger element is on the row immediately above the dropdown. If any wrapping occurs in between them, the dropdown will be displayed too low.

So here's what I believe to be the right way of doing it:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="vue-app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        A column.
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        You should <span onMouseOver="this.style.background='#AFF'" onMouseOut="this.style.background='#FFF'" class="dropdown">
          <span data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                click
          </span>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <span class="dropdown-item-text">Dropdown item text</span>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </span> a word.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You obviously no longer need Vue for this to work. All the heavy lifting of positioning the dropdown is done by Bootstrap's js. An interesting use of Vue here would be to dynamically place the dropdown when any word is clicked, while holding it in a template and dynamically rendering where required. Another note: you might want to look into BootstrapVue - it's a jQuery-free set of Bootstrap components built with Vue, for Vue. It's really intuitive and works well. If you want to use Vue and Bootstrap, you should give it a go.

Comment: what you described is my final goal. I want to have multiple words that trigger the dropdown. The dropdown should appear right under the cursor (aka any word) and dynamically load  dropdown content based on a chosen word. And I think displaying content under the cursor would do the trick, while current solutions would require me to code multiple buttons - each with a clickable word. I guess I simplified my question too much, that it allowed many alternative solutions :)